# Corrupted google font inside swiper slider

Tags: css, fonts, swiper.js, google-font-api, google-fonts

I've got little problem with some words inside swiper slider (these with polish chars). I'm using google font's Montserrat. It happens only inside swiper slider. It looks like this:
[image]

Online version here: (section our perks [Co zyskujesz z Greenworks?])
http://greenworks.prexperting.com.pl#our-perks

I'm using https://developers.google.com/fonts/docs/webfont_loader for loading fonts.

I'd really appreciate your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, thanks to w3c validator :)
C[image: Text run is not in Unicode Normalization Form]
I've copied text from pdf and some words were in different unicode standard. Retyped those words and all is working now.